# Highcharts Word cloud,I need to display table for chart data properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a wordcloud of Highcharts. Here already table is displaying for the chart.But instead of name and weight its displaying category and Occurrences inside thead. Here I need to display name and weight in heading of the table.Can anyone please help me.Here is the code below.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/wordcloud.js"></script>
<div class="chart-outer">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <!-- data table is inserted here -->
</div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script><!-- at bottom -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script><!-- at bottom -->
```

### script

```
var data = [{
    name: 'Lorem',
    weight: 100
}, {
    name: 'Ipsum',
    weight: 50
}, {
    name: 'Dolor',
    weight: 41
}];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'wordcloud',
        data: data,
        name: 'Occurrences'
    }],

    exporting: {
        showTable: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious to me what you are trying to accomplish, but I think you want to replace the table headings from "Category" and "Occurrences" to "Name" and "Weight", respectively.

If so, this configuration might work for you: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bhodcqm/1/)

```
 exporting: {
    showTable: true,
    tableCaption: 'Data table',
    csv: {
      // This function is called for each column header.
      columnHeaderFormatter: function (item, key) {
        if (!item || item instanceof Highcharts.Axis) {
          return 'Name';
        }
        // Item is not axis, now we are working with series.
        return 'Weight';
      }
    }
  }
```